# Question about degree of a irreducible polynomial and field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field and $p \in F[x] $ an irreducible polynomial. Let $K$ be a finite extension of $F$. How can I prove that if the degree of $p$ doesn't divide $[K:F] $, then $p$ doesn't have any roots in $K$?

Comment: Assume $x\in K, p(x) =0$. Then $[K : F] = [K:F(x)][F(x):F]$. But since $p$ is irreducible, $[F(x):F] =...$ ?

Comment: @Max : don't use $x$ for the root

Comment: If $p \in F[x]$ is irreducible and $p(a) = 0$ for some $a \in K$, then $L = F(a) \cong F[x]/(p(x))$  is a subfield of $K$. Thus $[K:F] = [K:L][L:F] = [K:L] [F[x]/(p(x)):F] = [K:L]  \deg(p)$ (for showing $[K:F] = [K:L] [L:F]$ consider the case $K = L(b)$ and generalize to $K = L(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of this irreducible $p \in F[x]$.  What is the degree of the extension $F(\alpha) / F$ ?

If $\alpha \in K$, we necessarily have a tower of fields $F \subset F(\alpha) \subset K$.  Think about the [multiplicativity formula for degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees).